# Finding a table on a webpage with Power Query - table is not always in the same location

Tags: web-scraping, powerquery

I use Power Query to scrape a webpage that has multiple tables on it.  The tables can move around so one week it may be the second table, the next the 3rd, then back to the 2nd the next week.  The table data does have the same text in the first column so I can select it if I can find the entry.

[image: The result of the first step is:]

My code is as follows.  The issue is the Source{2} can be a different number based on the actual page layout.

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://www.eia.gov/naturalgas/weekly/#tabs-supply-1")),
    Data0 = Source{2}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type","U.S. natural gas supply - ","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1"}),
    RecRepl = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value",null, each _[Column1], Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column2"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(RecRepl,{"Column1"}),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Removed Columns",1),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Top Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in
    #"Promoted Headers"
```

How can I search the table in the Data column to find the row I need?

Thanks!!!

I've tried a variety of steps but have been unable to find the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

This code looks for the *phrase* **Henry Hub** in column zero of all the tables in the Data column, and figures out which one has it. It then filters for **true** and pulls the contents (of the first match).  You can adjust what you are looking for in terms of column to search, text to search for, and take it from there

```
let Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://www.eia.gov/naturalgas/weekly/#tabs-supply-1")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each List.Contains(Table.Column([Data],Table.ColumnNames([Data]){0}),"Henry Hub")),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each [Custom] = true),
Data0 = #"Filtered Rows"{0}[Data]
in Data0
```

[image]

**EDIT**
This code looks for the *word* **Henry** in column zero of all the tables in the Data column, and figures out which one has it. It then filters for **true** and pulls the contents (of the first match).  You can adjust what you are looking for in terms of column to search, text to search for, and take it from there

```
let Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://www.eia.gov/naturalgas/weekly/#tabs-supply-1")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each List.Count(List.FindText(Table.Column([Data],Table.ColumnNames([Data]){0}),"Henry"))>0),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each [Custom] = true),
Data0 = #"Filtered Rows"{0}[Data]
in Data0
```

Comment: This code is working, except now I need to look for "Henry" and not just "Henry Hub".  Is that possible?  I've tried to use Text.Start around Table.ColumnNames([Data]){0} but that didn't work.  From what I read about the List.Contains hat should be a text field. Am I missing something?  Thanks for your previous advice...very helpful and timely.

Comment: how about #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each List.Count(List.FindText(Table.Column([Data],Table.ColumnNames([Data]){0}),"Henry"))>0),

Comment: you can't use List.Contains since that matches the entire contents of each item in the list. You  would first have to split the list with a transform and Text.Split.  I think this is easier. Please make future questions their own new question. Thanks